# Reading multiple txt files from multiple folders

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system

I have 20 folders, each containing 50 txt files, I need to read all of them in order to compare the word counts of each folder. I know how to read multiple files in one folder, but it is slow, is there a more efficient way instead of reading the folder one by one like below?

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import os
import glob

1. folder1

folder_path = '/home/runner/Final-Project/folder1'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print (filename)
    print (len(text))

2. folder2

folder_path = '/home/runner/Final-Project/folder2'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print (filename)
    print (len(text))
```

Comment: Are all the folders under the same root folder, for example `/home/runner/Final-Project`?

Comment: @MattDmo yes, all of the folders are under the same root!

Comment: @Maibaozi, what do you want really? You want to read all files without have to write the path to each directory?

Comment: No, there really isn't a way.

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha, in this step, I want to add up all the word counts of the txt files in each folder separately and see which folder contains the longest texts. I need to plot them in the end, but there are just too many folders

Comment: @martineau, really ?? I thought this should be not that hard, I was stuck just because I am new to python..

Comment: Really. What are you planning on doing with the data from all these files? Are you thinking of doing some sort of concurrent processing of them — if not, what's the point?

Comment: @martineau Sir I just need to compare the word counts of each folder and plot them in the end..thank you for telling me the word 'concurrent processing'..

Comment: That kind of processing is something that *could* be done to the files in parallel. I suggest using the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module to read the files and count the words in each one (one thread per file or via a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar using `glob` like you have, but with the directory names.

```
folder_path = '/home/runner/Final-Project'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'*','*.txt')):
    # process your files
```

The first `'*'` in the `os.path.join()` represents directories of any name. So calling `glob.glob()` like this will go through and find any text file in any direct sub-directory within `folder_path`

Answer (score 1):

Below function will return list of files in all the directories and sub-directories without using glob. Read from the list of files and open to read.

```
def list_of_files(dirName):
    files_list = os.listdir(dirName)
    all_files = list()
    for entry in files_list:
        # Create full path
        full_path = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            all_files = all_files + list_of_files(full_path)
        else:
            all_files.append(full_path)

    return all_files

print(list_of_files(<Dir Path>))  # <Dir Path>  ==> your directory path
```